# Shiny : How to get vector of options in selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

My ui.R file has a selectInput like this:

```
selectInput("cluster", "Cluster:",
                                 c("Total" = "Total","East"="East",                                 
                                   "South"="South", )
```

where "Total" or "South" are supposed to be a vector of colnames list.

Like 
`East is : East<-c("Strasbourg","Grenoble","Nice")`
And 
`South is : South<-("Nice","Montpellier","Marseille")`

like in `server.r` file :

i would like to do something like that :

```
  resultscluster<-reactive({
   mydataframe[,(names(mydataframe) %in% input$cluster)]

  })
```

When I run the App the ui.R does not know what "cluster".

thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I would probably just use a `switch` statement.  I also took the liberty of adding a `validate` statement requiring an option to be selected.

```
library(shiny)

East <- c("Strasbourg","Grenoble","Nice") 
South <- c("Nice","Montpellier","Marseille")
Total <- c("Strasbourg","Grenoble","Nice",
           "Montpellier","Marseille", "coolPlace1", "coolplace2")

# some play data
mydataframe <- as.data.frame(replicate(7, rnorm(10)))
colnames(mydataframe) <- Total

runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(
      div(),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("cluster","Cluster:",
                    c("East","South","Total"))),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table"))),

    server = function(input, output){

      resultscluster<-reactive({
        validate(
          need(!is.null(input$cluster),
               "Please select a clutser")
          )

        switch(input$cluster,
          East =  mydataframe[,(names(mydataframe) %in% c("Strasbourg","Grenoble","Nice"))],
          South = mydataframe[,(names(mydataframe) %in% c("Nice","Montpellier","Marseille"))],
          Total = mydataframe[,(names(mydataframe) %in% c("Strasbourg","Grenoble","Nice",
                                                          "Montpellier","Marseille", "coolPlace1", "coolplace2"))],
        )

      })

      output$table <- renderTable(resultscluster())
    }
    ))
```

Comment: thanks...."switch" ....of course ! thank you so much and for validate statement suggestion too.

Comment: Glad to help, please be sure to accept the answer if this satisfies you.